# Changing date of GregorianCalendar not saving

Tags: java, calendar

I have a class that takes a calendar object and prints out the current date. After printing the current date it gives an option to print the previous or next date, however the previous and next aren't working properly.

```
public void viewDate(Calendar greg) {
//greg is a GregorianCalendar passed in from classA
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in());
    cal = greg.getInstance();
    //print current date

System.out.println("P or N");
    char request = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    if(request == 'P') {
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        viewDate(cal);
    {//else next...
```

After changing current date -1 and printing I could see that the date has changed back one day, but when I pass cal back into the method it doesn't save that change. Why?

Comment: `greg.getInstance()`? No compiler warning?

Comment: A Calendar was created in ClassA then passed into this method. There's no compiler error for greg.getInstance(), cal is another Calendar object I created in classB. input is a Scanner(System.in);

Comment: error != warning. You're invoking a static method on an instance. Why are you creating a new instance at all?

Comment: oh, you're right. There is a warning. I'm somewhat new to Java and first time dealing with Calendar. ClassB actually has multiple methods that take in a Calendar from ClassA, when I made changes with one method those changes stayed, so I tried getInstance. I didn't know how to set the date back to the current date after it changed....

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but if you want to "modify" the passed calendar (e.g. by shifting days), you shouldn't create a new one. Just work with the passed instance `greg`.

Comment: after I've made changes, could you tell me how to set it back to the current date/time? This is the reason why I tried getInstance().